# custom annotations for method in java

Tags: java, annotations

I am new to annotations in java, I want to have an annotation on method to do some stuff for me like:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface LogActivity {
    String logMessage() default "default message";
}
```

I want to have some methods in different classes like:

```
public class A {

@LogActivity(logMessage = "called foo() in class A")
    public void foo() {
        // some code
    }
}
```

and

```
public class B {
@LogActivity(logMessage = "called foo() in class B")
public void foo() {// some code}

@LogActivity(logMessage = "called foo1() in class B")
public void foo1() {// some code}
}
```

I need a method which will print these logMessages on the screen.
I just need help writing the method which will be executed after the call to these foo and foo1 goes but before their execution starts.

> Blockquote I need this annotation in any number of classes in my project so I cannot prefer to do something like:

```
Method [] methods = Class.forName(theObject.getClass().getName()).getMethods();
```

and

```
LogActivity logActivity = methods[i].getAnnotation(LogActivity.class);
```

I googled some things but didn't really understand the solution.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I could use AOP for this but the requirement is different than that.

Comment: Please work through this [MKYong tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-custom-annotations-example/).

Comment: What you're describing is *exactly* AOP, and you should take a look at AspectJ and Spring AOP.

Comment: I already mentioned that my requirement is not AOP. The logging messages was just an example that I put here